# Zkoss doesn't inject my component into the controller

Tags: java, user-interface, dependency-injection, zk

I've got a weird problem with injecting a component into my controller:

```
public class AnalyticsController {

  @Wire("#fileSourceTree")
  private Tree fileSourceTree;
  @Wire("#chart")
  private Chart chart;
  ...

  @Override
  public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
    super.doAfterCompose(comp);

    TreeModel<TreeNode<Object>> model = session.getFileSourceTreeModel();

    if(model == null) {
      model = createFileSourceTreeModel();
      session.setFileSourceTreeModel(model);
    }

    fileSourceTree.setModel(model);

    log.debug("Chart is initialized? {}", chart != null);
    chart.setModel(new ChartModel(new LinkedList<ChartData>(), "", ""));
  }
```

analytics.zul

```
<?page title="Ana File Analytics" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<?style src="css/nv.d3.css"?>
<zk>
  <borderlayout apply="my.package.AnalyticsController">
  ...
    <center>
        <vlayout>
            <hlayout valign="middle" style="padding: 10px 20px 5px">
                <label value="Type:" />
                <combobox id="statisticsTypeCombobox" model="${$composer.statisticsTypeModel}" />
                <label value="Interval:" />
                <combobox id="intervalCombobox" model="${$composer.intervalModel}" />
                <label value="From: " />
                <datebox id="fromDatebox" />
                <label value="to" />
                <datebox id="toDatebox" />
                <button id="showButton" label="Show" />
            </hlayout>
            <div style="padding: 5px 30px">
                <label id="chartHeader"
                    style="font: bold 28px Verdana Arial sans-serif; color: #2a5dda" />
            </div>
            <chart id="chart" height="500px" />
        </vlayout>
    </center>
```

I got `NullPointerException` when trying to set model (`chart.setModel()`) in the last line like if chart wasn't injected (but `fileSourceTree` is injected correctly). The problem is that when try it on my local machine it works but when I deployed it to our dev environment I received this NPE (I had a similar problem in other component too). I don't know what's the reason of such a behavior and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller needs to inherit from a composer such as `SelectorComposer<T>`.

From the [ZK manual](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVC/Controller/Composer#Implement_Composers):

> To simplify the implementation of the controller part of UI, ZK provides several skeleton implementations. For example, SelectorComposer, as one of the most popular skeletons, wires components, variables and event listeners automatically based on Java annotations you specify.

So simply change that line in your code:

```
public class AnalyticsController extends SelectorComposer<BorderLayout>
```